# Node JS Sequelize WHERE LIKE operator in raw query is throwing error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sql-like

I am building a Node JS application. I am using Sequelize for the database operations. Now, I am having a problem with using the LIKE operator with raw queries.

I have the query as follow.

```
let offset = (page > 1)? (page - 1) * recordPerPage: 0;
    let where = { }
    let sql = 'SELECT "Users"."id", "Users"."name", "Users"."email"';
    sql = sql + ' FROM "Users"';
    sql = sql + ' WHERE "Users"."id" != :myUserId';
    where.myUserId = myUserId;
    if (keyword) {
      where.keyword = keyword;
      sql = sql + ' AND ("Users"."email" LIKE "%:keyword%" OR "Users"."name" LIKE "%:keyword%")'
    }
    if (parseInt(roleType) > 0) {
      // get the role is because role is the type
      let role = await Role.findOne({
        where: {
          type: {
            [Op.eq]: roleType
          }
        }
      })
      where.role = role.id;
      sql = sql + ' AND "Users"."id" IN (SELECT "UserRoles"."user_id" FROM "UserRoles" WHERE "UserRoles"."role_id" =:role)';
    }
    sql = sql + ' ORDER BY "Users"."name" ASC, "Users"."id" ASC';

    where.offset = offset;
    where.limit = recordPerPage;
    sql = sql + ' LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';

    let users = await database.sequelize.query(sql, {
      replacements: where,
      type: QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
```

When I pass the keyword that is used with the LIKE operator, I am getting the following error.

```
`column "%'TEST'%" does not exist`
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi! try running it in debug/verbose mode, to see what is the full SQL that is generated.
Also, have you tried with removing `"` from the query?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing "" from LIKE "%var%". It does not work either.

Comment: ouch, yeah I would try to get what sql query sequelize is getting
have you tried that query with a sql client? (just to see if that's what you want to get)

Comment: Hi, the query is right, it just does not work in Sequelize.

Comment: oh I think I know what's happening here, take a look at the last example here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements
there is no `"` for the placeholder, but also, the `keyword` should include the `%` inside.

Comment: (happy to add this as a proper answer if that solves the problem :D )

Comment: Please, add the answer, I can upvote too if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is the solution. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the last example in [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements):
there is no `"` for the placeholder in the sql, but also, the `keyword` should include the `%` **inside**, as part of its content.

Here's the example from the docs:

```js
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :search_name',
  {
    replacements: { search_name: 'ben%' },
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);
```